# How can I get POST data from a static page into XSLT? chicken and egg?

Tags: forms, xslt, if-statement, post, submit

Using XLST 2.0, I have a .html form, and on it an input like

```
<form method="post" action="perlscript.cgi" name="formname">
  .
  .
<input name="myvar" onchange="form.submit">
```

then later, I have

```
<xsl:if test="myvar=1">
  .
  .
</xsl:if>
```

I realize this ISN'T the way to do this because the XSLT doesn’t map the `<input name=.. >` to the `"myvar=1"`. I think it's probably seeking it from the XML namespace.

I googled XSLT POST , etc, but I don't see examples of this syntax.I immediately get a "Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed" error with no line number.

If I comment out the `<xsl:if>` and the `</sxl:if>`, the form is OK , so I'm sure that's the problem.

So basically I need a way to either merge the XML and FORM namespaces, or a way to access the FORM data.

Comment: I meant...using XLST 2.0, I have a .html form, and on it an input like
<code>
<form method="post" action="perlscript.cgi" name="formname">
  .
  .
<input name="myvar" onchange="form.submit">
</code>

then later, I have
<code>
<xsl:if test="myvar=1">
  .
  .
</xsl:if>
</code>

Comment: I realize this question formatting is FUBAR..  if I could delete or edit it I would. If an admin wants to delete it please proceed!

Comment: Maybe a simpler question - is there a way to have MULTIPLE <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="daa.xslt"> lines in an XML file, and a way to apply one for one state, and another for another state? I hate to have 1000's of line XML files cp'ed to just vary that one line in each...